# How to add a delay in loading a Shopify snippet?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to add a delay in the call of the snippet.

Currently I am calling the snippet via an include. `{% include 'mySnippet' %}`

How can I add a delay of 1000ms before calling the snippet?

Inside the snippet there is a form that uses liquid objects to define the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Include files are rendered server side and you cannot touch that pipeline. Instead, do the more obvious thing and render your snippet HTML in a container that is hidden. Use Javascript to unhide the container when you are ready, for example 1000ms after the page assets have loaded.

Comment: Great idea. Going home for the day now, but will try this tomorrow.

Comment: this didn't work. I have the wrapped the hidden form in a div with display:none. Then I set a 10 second timer to display. However, the include is still getting added. The problem is that I have an unknown script that is loading late. I did document read etc... However, if I wait 2 seconds after load my new script works.

Comment: Of course the include file is included. It is rendered no matter what. The point is, you render it hidden. That is server side. You unhide it client side. Why is that simple pattern an issue?

Comment: I want to grab the text that appears in the DOM. There is something that is loading after the DOM pageload, but I don't know what is even using the network tab. If I wait for 1 second, I can grab the text via javascript. However, I thought if I could just load my hidden form (include snippet) 1 second late, it would be easier. However, the form uses liquid objects as the input values. I did use a display none with the include wrapped in a div and after 1 second display block. I am just going to rewrite the whole thing in Javascript and stay away from liquid for this. Thanks!